# Create a view of nodes that are not referenced in any entity reference field of another content type

Tags: views, 8

How can I create a view of nodes that are not referenced in an entity reference field assigned to another content type?

I have a Profiles content type and a Publications content type.  The Publications content type has an entity reference field by which the publications can be associated with one or more Profiles.  How can I list all Profiles nodes that are not referenced in any Publication?